# Parcel 2 - Multiple outputs with different dist-dir? [scss -> css]

Tags: node.js, webpack, parcel, parceljs

Im about to go from webpack to Parcel, but some problems has come to my attention with how to put everything together. Especially since my project structure is a bit different than the one proposed in the documentation.

Here's my project structure

```
root
- package.json
- js
-- app.js
-- shim.js
- scss
-- main.scss
public
```

And I want to put the 'js' files into public/ and then the scss-file (main.scss) into public/css, but I can't figure out how this is supposed to work with 'targets' and 'source' in my package.json.

Here's how I want it to look after the servings;

```
root
- package.json
- js
-- app.js
-- shim.js
- scss
-- main.scss
public
- css
-- main.css
- app.js
- shim.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "embed",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel serve ./src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html",
    "dev": "parcel serve ./js/app.js ./js/shim.js --dist-dir ./public"
  },
  "source": ["./scss/main.scss"],
  "css": "./scss/main.scss",
  "targets": {
    "css": { "distDir": "./public/css" }
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.2%",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.5",
    "parcel": "next",
    "sass": "^1.32.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta2"
  }
}
```

The above configuration doesnt create any css-file at all. But if I add:
"dev": "parcel serve ./js/app.js ./js/shim.js ./scss/main.scss -out --dist-dir ./public"

It generates a css file into public/scss/. And not public/css which I actually want. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: I went back to using webpack..

Comment: I'd like to know the solution to this Parcel issue too. Especially regarding how to tell parcel where to put the dist folder